# Export specific columns to Excel sheet with DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a VBA module that currently exports several Access tables to Excel sheets.

Is there a way to selectively export columns so that only a handful would be exported?

here's the current code for one Excel sheet:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tChart1_Reportable", SavePath, False, "Campus1"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tChart2_Reportable", SavePath, False, "Campus2"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tChart4_Reportable", SavePath, False, "Campus3"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tChart9_Reportable", SavePath, False, "Campus4"
```

Comment: You can base your export on a Query or just some SQL which has the columns you want

Comment: Imo for complex exports, using OLE automation and .CopyFromRecordset is often the way to go. That gives you more control, allows you to export to different sheets, and make it exactly like you want it.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do that with the code I provided?  Thanks!